# Canvas : Getting rid of style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

How to get rid of style which is automatically generated by canvas?

```
Chrome:
<canvas id="g_2" width="604" height="304" style="-webkit-user-select: none; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); width: 302px; height: 152px;"></canvas>


Firefox:
<canvas height="157" width="1076" style="-moz-user-select: none; width: 302px; height: 152px;" id="g_2"></canvas>
```

P.S : I am not using any javascript to add style.

To create canvas, I am using angularJS which is ng-repeating over an canvas element using an array, to add a new canvas , index is appended to that array. Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="tab-content" data-ng-repeat="tab in someArray">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
      <canvas id="someID_[[tab]]"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

After canvas element is created, setting width and height as follows:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId); 
canvas.width = width; 
canvas.height = height;
```

Comment: `<canvas>` doesn't automatically add anything - that looks like some of it is from Chrome, perhaps an extension, but the width and height must be being set somewhere. How is this canvas created?

Comment: Just this much of html, <canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>

Comment: Then I am setting height and width as follows:                                                  
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

Comment: Please add a more complete code sample.

Comment: Updated with extra code.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the canvas height and width also set its style

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId); 
canvas.width = width; 
canvas.height = height;
canvas.style = '';
```